# Best practice for multiple forms accessing same method

Tags: c#, winforms

the background to my question is that I'm doing some home-projects and I'm starting to get the hang of some things in my programming. But I came across something that left me wondering; must I write the same code over and over in each of the forms. That can't be right.

So let's say I have a piece of code that handles catches into a logfile. It works nice with my form and outputs the catches in a structured way with a timestamp and from which method the error came. Is it poosible to reuse the code in form1 by accessing it from form2 and if form2 has a catch it will send the parameter to form1 and have it printed in the logfile aswell as maybe even return a value to form2.

Is this possible or should it be rewritten in form2. And if it is possible, how would one access it?

Also, would like to know what is best practice. I understan from reading around on this forum that a lot of solutions are possible, but some of them are not always the propper way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: You can also build your own library and add a Reference to the assembly, since it appears to be something you may want use elsewhere (other Projects/Solutions).

Comment: Don't forget the fact that "forms are classes as well". So use your object oriented design skills to handle the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a class that has that common method which returns the output that both forms can recognise. Each form will then reference that class and use that common method. This is the basic principle of Object Oriented Programming.

You could also use a reference variable into that method which would mean you don’t need to necessarily return anything to the form. This is known as pass by reference. Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

I’m not exactly sure on best practice but would suggest having a logToFile method in a logger class that can be used by both forms. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Hi @Rob Husband! Thank you for your advice, it was just what I needed; someone to point me in the right direction! I've now successully created my first class. The problem I had while doing so was that, unlike sending a parameter to another method, I needed to also initiated the class to be able to access the methos within the class i.e. :

`var inst = new TestClass();
                    string docname = await inst.FilNamn(r1);`

Is there an easier or neater way to write this?

Comment: To do it without initiating the class then you would need to make the class static. This means you can do something like this: string docname = await TestClass.FileName(rl).